# Global variables or Provider not allowing incrementation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, variables, iteration, global, provider

Global variables or Provider, won't allow me to increment the round number or the current player number.

I'm trying to cycle through rounds in a game, and for each round all the players should play one by one.
I have the players in a PlayerData Provider. Also there I've put currentPlayerNumber and currentRoundNumber.

I'm taking the totalRoundNumber from the previous page, passed in the constructor of the current page.

```
MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    //if current round is less than the entire number of rounds then play
                    if (Provider.of<PlayerData>(context).currentRoundNumber < widget.totalRoundNumber) {
                      //if current player number is less than the total of players
                      if (Provider.of<PlayerData>(context).currentRoundNumber<
                          Provider.of<PlayerData>(context).playerCount) {
                        //go to the voting page to select yes/no
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/voting');
                      }
                      //if current player number is equal to the total # of players (all the players have played)
                      if (Provider.of<PlayerData>(context)
                              .currentPlayerNumber ==
                          Provider.of<PlayerData>(context).playerCount) {
                        //increase current round number and pass to next round
                        Provider.of<PlayerData>(context).incrementCurrentRoundNumber();
                        //set currentplayer number to 0 and the players start over to the next round
                        Provider.of<PlayerData>(context)
                            .resetCurrentPlayerNumber();
                      }
                      // } else {
                      //   //TODO go to the results page and pass the results
                      // }
                    }
                  },
```

in the voting page I have the following:

```
child: MaterialButton(
            //if the player managed to succeed the challenge
            child: Text('He did it!'),
            onPressed: () {
              //increase the score of the player
              //setPlayerScore(playerNumber) function increases the score by 1
              Provider.of<PlayerData>(context)
                  .setPlayerScore(
                //this is the current player number, for which the score is to be increased
                //also taken from the PlayerData
                  Provider.of<PlayerData>(context).currentPlayerNumber);
               //this is a void method, that increases the currentPlayerNumber by 1
              Provider.of<PlayerData>(context).incrementCurrentPlayerNumber();
              //navigate back to the previous page
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/questions');
            },
          ),
```

It works incrementing once the current player number and then I get:

```
The method '>' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: >(1)
```

I tried:

- global variables for the currentPlayerNumber and currentRound number
- building a separate Provider just for these two variables

I really can't think of another solution...

Player data file:

```
class PlayerData extends ChangeNotifier {
List<Player> _players = [];
Game _game = Game(currentRoundNumber: 1,currentPlayerNumber: 0);

UnmodifiableListView<Player> get players {
return UnmodifiableListView(_players);
```

}

```
int get currentRoundNumber{
  return _game.currentRoundNumber;
```

}

```
int get currentPlayerNumber{
  return _game.currentPlayerNumber;
}

void resetCurrentPlayerNumber (){
_game.currentPlayerNumber =0;
}

void incrementCurrentPlayerNumber() {
  _game.currentPlayerNumber ++;
}

void incrementCurrentRoundNumber(){
  _game.currentRoundNumber++;
}

void resetCurrentRoundNumber(){
  _game.currentRoundNumber = 0;
}


int get playerCount {
print('player count: ${_players.length}');
    return _players.length;
```

}

```
void addPlayer(String newPlayerName) {
if (_players.length < 8) {
  _players.add(Player(name: newPlayerName,score: 0));
  notifyListeners();
}
```

}

```
void deletePlayer(Player player) {
_players.remove(player);
notifyListeners();
```

}

```
void resetPlayerScore(Player player) {
player.resetScore();
notifyListeners();
```

}

```
Player getPlayer(int i) {
print(i);
if (i < _players.length) {
  return _players[i];
} else
  return null;
```

}

```
void setPlayerScore(int playerNumber) {
_players[playerNumber].score++;
notifyListeners();
```

}

```
void updatePlayer(Player player) {
notifyListeners();
```

}
}

Comment: I don't think your problem is related to `Provider`, but rather to your implementation of `PlayerData`. Can you share the implementation so that we can have a look?

Comment: @rgsi I added it :)

Comment: Hmm sorry, I can't really find an obvious problem. I don't even see where you would call `>`... can you provide a stacktrace?